# Is there any way to provide additional information about member variables in python?

Tags: python, tags, introspection

I want to create a function that creates a dialog from different classes, providing a text (or checkbox for boolean, etc) input for each member variable. I understand how to get a list of the variables from a class and how to use hints to specify variable types, but I'd like to provide additional information (i.e. the description, a default value, is it required, is it a password, etc.)

I was hoping to use something like annotations to further describe each variable for this function to better infer how to present the input to the user (but they are only available for functions and not variables.)

Any suggestions would be most welcome

Comment: One option is to make all variables instances of specific dataclasses where you can define other parameters that you need.

Comment: @pavel that is a great idea, but the variables are all sqlalchemy data types, further confusing things

Comment: Can you show an example of one such variable?

Comment: So I wound up giving up on this as the classes I was trying to implement gui's for required too much specific code for them.  FWIW, I started by adding a function call in the class for each sqlachemy variable.  This wound up being a bust as the class variables aren't available until the class has been completely described.  I moved the function call to the constructor but decided I didn't want to call it every time an object was instanciated.  I finally wound up with an abstract class with a method that  added to a dictionary of descriptions for each variable.  I finally tossed it all.